# Single instruction to load shifted immediate value into a register?

Tags: assembly, arm, instructions

I can't seem to find a way to, with a single instruction, place an immediate value into a register in a position that is not the lowest bit.

For instance, suppose you want your register to be `r1 = 0x00110000`. Then, a multi instruction way to do this is.

```
mov r1, #0x11
lsl r1, #16
```

I'm working with several devices and some of them allow immediate values up to 32 bits, but most don't, so I can only use the basic ARM instructions.

Comment: Loading from a literal pool is a single instruction but is not smaller in size. Unclear what your objective is.

Comment: Wait what?  Your title says store to memory (AFAIK all ARM store instructions use any spare bits for addressing mode offsets, not immediate store data).  But then you're just talking about *loading* an immediate value into a **register**.  `mov r1, #0x11 << 16` assembles fine; use that.  I think Thumb2 mode allows a rotated 8-bit immediate, and your assembler knows how to encode any encodeable immediate.

Comment: Ah thank you @PeterCordes ! I didn't even think about using that notation! And yes, there's a mistake in the title, I'll correct it now

Comment: Or you can just use `ldr r1, =0x00110000` and let the assembler sort it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let your assembler encode the shift / rotate for you, by giving it the `0x00110000` value.

Most assemblers (including all ARM assemblers?) support assemble-time constant expressions so you can write

```
mov r1, #0x11 << 16
```

This will assemble in ARM mode to `11 18 a0 e3`.  But in Thumb mode it requires ARMv6 Thumb2.  See http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1361289878994.htm for the available forms of MOV.

Probably a better choice is and LDR pseudo-instruction that lets the assembler pick between a PC-relative load (from a literal pool) or a mov-immediate with some encoding.  http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armasm/armasm_dom1359731145835.htm (That's keil's doc for their assembler, but GAS and clang also support the same syntax.)

```
ldr r1, =0x11 << 16
```

> I'm working with several devices

Consider rebuilding for each device so you can make code optimized for each one.  Especially if you use `ldr reg, =value` - it can use `mov.w reg, #imm16` when available.

> and some of them allow immediate values up to 32 bits

If you're talking about ARMv6T2 `movt` / `movw`, that's two 32-bit instructions each providing a 16-bit half.

No ARM is capable of encoding any arbitrary 32-bit constant with a single instruction; that would leave no bits for an opcode in a 32-bit instruction.

Comment: *Not with a single instruction* - I would correct by adding "or not an arbitrary value". Certain ranges of 32-bit immediate values can be generated using the shifter (in a number of different ways between ARM32 and Thumb2). See [here](http://class.ece.iastate.edu/cpre288/resources/docs/Thumb-2SupplementReferenceManual.pdf) for Thumb-2, "4.2 Immediate constants".

Comment: @tum_: I meant not an *arbitrary* 32-bit immediate.  Yes ARM immediates aren't always just simple zero-extended or sign-extended, so the encodeable values aren't just a contiguous 0..n range.  To me "immediate values up to 32 bits" means a 4 byte immediate which is obvious nonsense.  x86 can do that, ARM can't.  But anyway, I found a clearer way to say that, thanks.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you meant, @Peter. Added this comment for the OP's attention mostly, based on the fact that they seem to ask specifically about "shifted immediates" (for the reason unknown to me) and also mention "several devices" but give no further details.

Comment: not all assemblers support that syntax but for gas at least the ldr r0,=something will convert to a mov if possible for that instruction set if not it will load the value from a nearby pool if possible. while pseudocode it is the simplest way to not have to get into the details of what can be done or not for a particular value (for each of the instruction sets).

Comment: @old_timer: I figured; I got lazy and didn't look for a duplicate.  If you know of a good one, I can still close this.  (Or close them as duplicates of this, and add some more links to this if we don't have a good canonical.)

Comment: ditto, I simply repeat the same type of answer too that was directed at the OP.